# Installation of DOMPDF with PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, tcpdf, dompdf

I am having problems exporting Excel files to `.pdf` format using `DOMPDF`. I'm using `PHPExcel (1.7.9, 2013-06-02)`, `TCPDF (6.2.13)` and `Dompdf (0.7.0)`. For the moment the testing of `Dompdf` is done on a `Win10/Wampserver 3.0` machine, but I'll have to use it on live server `(Apache2.2.22 and PHP5.4.35)`. All three packages work OK if used alone, as expected (`PHPExcel` and `TCPDF` for more than three years on both test and live servers, and `Dompdf` was installed just recently on the test bed).
In addition I've been able to produce `.pdf` files with `PHPExcel` and `TCPDF`. The code is practically the same as in some of the `PHPExcel` examples and the crucial part is the following:

```
require_once __phpexcel__ . 'PHPExcel.php';
PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_TCPDF, __tcpdf__);`
```

Where `__phpexcel__` and `__tcpdf__` are constants pointing to the directories where the `PHPExcel.php` and `tcpdf.php` reside.
`PHPExcel+TCPDF` work fine, but they produce a rather large `.pdf` file (1.2MB for couple of cells with UTF-8 characters).

However, if I try to convert the same `.xlsx` file using `Dompdf` I have a problem. The crucial code in this case is

```
require_once __phpexcel__ . 'PHPExcel.php';
PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF, __dompdf__);`
```

`__dompdf__` in this case is the directory where `Dompdf` files reside
(among others: `dirs lib`, etc and `autoload.inc.php`).

The error I receive is:

> Fatal error: Class 'DOMPDF' not found in **phpexcel**\PHPExcel\Writer\PDF\DomPDF.php on line 36.

After examining the file `__phpexcel__\PHPExcel\Writer\PDF\DomPDF.php` I found that line 30 in that file is
`$pdfRendererClassFile = PHPExcel_Settings::getPdfRendererPath() . '/dompdf_config.inc.php';` and there is no `dompdf_config.inc.php` file in the distribution of Dompdf!
Changing `dompdf_config.inc.php` to `autoload.inc.php` doesn't work!

I'm bewildered what should I do. The samples provided at `PHPExcel` and `DOMPDF` site do not provide any answers, or I'm not able to find them.

Comment: Could you do anything to change the return value of `PHPExcel_Settings::getPdfRendererPath()`? Seems to me that should be user-defined, and not dependent on the distribution.

Comment: That's not the point. The value of `PHPExcel_Settings::getPdfRendererPath()` is OK and it is set by `PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF, __dompdf__).
`PHPExcel` expects the file `dompdf_config.inc.php`, but there is no such file!

Comment: How are you installing the libraries? Dompdf stopped using the configuration file starting with 0.7.0 so you'll want to try using 0.6.2.